# in Excel VBA, how do I substitute local variables in a MATCH function in place of hard coded values?

Tags: excel, match, vba

I've written some VBA code that cycles through the rows of an open Excel datasheet doing an `Evaluate(Index(Match))` statement, that I found online, that searches for 2 values (LastName & LabCat) in a second Excel Workbook. The result (FirstName) is returned from the second Excel Workbook and stored in a local variable. I successfully return the value I'm looking for with this statement:

```
strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""Cain""&""ABO1"",'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000&'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

But what I haven't been able to solve is how to substitute local variables for the hard coded values, such as this statement (where I substitute the string "cain" with the variable strLastName and I substitute the string "ABO1" with the variable strLabCat):

```
strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""strLastName""&""strLabCat"",'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000&'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

This statement returns "Error 2042" into strFirstName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it but it's easy to get mixed up with all the ""double-double"" quotes you need in a string in order to assign "double quotes" to the value of the string.

### With your specific example, if *this* is successful:

```
strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""Cain""&""ABO1"",'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000&'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

**...but instead of hardcoding** *`Cain`* and *`AB01`*, you want to get the values from string variables as stated in your question, change the line to:

```
strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""" & strLastName & """&""" & strLabCat & """,'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000&'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

---

Backing up a bit, consider the following simple example of a string being assigned to a variable:

```
Option Explicit

Sub varTest1()
    Dim myGreeting As String
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is Juan and I live in Mexico"
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

Running this subroutine, causes a message to pop-up with a greeting from Juan.  Very basic, but note:

- The variable is explicitly declared.  It would work without the `As String` part but it's good coding practice to always specify a data type.
- I used the optional statement [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement).  If used, it must be the **first line in the module**, and only appear **once** per module.  What is does is ***force you*** to declare all variables and handle objects properly, by generating "pickier" errors during compilation or prior to code execution. Why would you want more errors?  Better **now** than [unexpectedly] later,  and is highly recommended to newer-coders and/or when troubleshooting.

Next, let's **replace** Juan's hardcoded name with another **variable**.

Still simple, like this:

```
Sub varTest2()
    Dim myGreeting As String, myName As String
    myName = "Juan"
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is " & myName & " and I live in Mexico"
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

Basically you're just [concatenating a string](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/concat2.php).  A plus symbol `+` works for adding strings *or* numbers together, but again, best practice is to stick with the one specifically meant for strings, which is the ampersand `&`.

Let's add another variable again:

```
Sub varTest3()
    Dim myGreeting As String, myName As String, myCountry As String
    myName = "Juan"
    myCountry = "Mexico"
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is " & myName & " and I live in " & myCountry
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

Same idea as #2; the reason I added example #2 is to demonstrate that if the variable is at **the end** of the string, there's no need for an additional `"` quote.

However if we wanted a period at the end of the sentence, the line would look like:

```
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is " & myName & " and I live in " & myCountry & "."
```

Note that **all of the above examples have identical results**.

---

### Adding Double-Quotes *within* the String:

This is where the `"` double quotation marks can get a little confusing, since they are needed around the text that you are assigning to the string, but ***how do we put them inside the string?***  Well there's a couple ways.

Backing up again, we could add **single quotes** `'` around the name like this:

```
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is 'Juan' and I live in Mexico."
```

...and the string would contain:

> Hello, My name is 'Juan' and I live in Mexico.

...but if we instead wanted ***double-quotes*** `"` around part od the string for cosmetic reasons like these examples, or for mandatory reasons like requirement in a formula (like your example), we can do one of two things:

- add the `"` symbol using the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character code of **34**.  The function in VBA would be `Chr(34)` as as a worksheet function `CHAR(34)`.
- or, each time we want a `"` double-quote, we use ***two double-quotes together*** `""` (or a quad-quote as I call it.)

For example, hardcoded:

```
Sub varTest4()
    Dim myGreeting As String
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is ""Juan"" and I live in Mexico."
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

This would display a popup message box that says:

> Hello, My name is "Juan" and I live in Mexico

Or, we could again use a variable with the name *and* double-quotes around it:

```
Sub varTest5()
    Dim myGreeting As String, myName As String
    myName = """Juan"""
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is " & myName & " and I live in Mexico"
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

...which will produce the same result as the previous example (#4).

Or we could add the double-quotes to `myGreeting` instead of via `myName`:\

```
Sub varTest6()
    Dim myGreeting As String, myName As String
    myName = "Juan"
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is """ & myName & """ and I live in Mexico"
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

...we will again get the exact same result as above.

And, to demonstrate what that would look like if we wanted double-quotes around *both* the Name *and* the Country (so with a double-quote appearing at the very end of the string):

```
Sub varTest7()
    Dim myGreeting As String, myName As String, myCountry As String
    myName = "Juan"
    myCountry = "Mexico"
    myGreeting = "Hello, My name is """ & myName & """ and I live in """ & myCountry & """"
    MsgBox myGreeting
End Sub
```

---

There are at least a couple ways to add a double-quote within a string:

- Using the `""` "quad-quote" as above, or,
- Using the ASCII character code (which is **34** for a double-quote.)

...because sometimes all these excessive quotes can get confusing.

For example, to show **three double-quotes**, like this:

> """

I would need to use:

### `MsgBox """"""""`

...that's **eight** double-quotes: one to begin the string, one to end the string, and three sets of two for each one to display. (*Would that be called an **Octo-quote**?!*)

We could display this:

> "Juan"

with:

```
MsgBox """Juan"""
```

...or exact same results (but a little cleaner *in my mind*):

```
MsgBox Chr(34) & "Juan" & Chr(34)
```

...so therefore changing the line in example #7, this:

```
myGreeting = "Hello, My name is " & Chr(34) & myName & Chr(34) & _
    " and I live in " & Chr(34) &  myCountry & Chr(34)
```

...would produce identical result as example #7 did:

> Hello, My name is "Juan" and I live in "Mexico"

---

Finally, one more thought about the example from your question, on the topic of clarity with confusing strings. You can use the **underscore** `_` as a "line continuation symbol" to break up a long line of code to multiple lines, making it easier to read, both in your VBA Editor (VBE), as well as for others to read *or copy/paste* when posting code on sites like this!

For example, my "correction" to your line of code was:

```
strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""" & strLastName & """&""" & strLabCat & """,'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000&'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

...one *loooong* line (and they can get [***much loooonger***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/limitations)!)

I didn't want to make my original response more confusing my adding extra symbols until I explained the quotes, but a *"cleaner"* to write lengthy lines is to add underscores anywhere you want to continue on the following line, like this:

```
 strFirstName = Evaluate("INDEX('[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$C$2:$C$1000, " & _
    "MATCH(""" & strLastName & """&""" & strLabCat & """,'[MyMatrix.xlsm]" & _
    "MySheet'!$B$2:$B$1000'[MyMatrix.xlsm]MySheet'!$H$2:$H$1000,0))")
```

You won't have to scroll-right in your VBE to see the code, and notice how Stack Overflow doesn't have to add the horizontal scroll bar either.

***Clear as mud?***  :-)

*Good Luck!*  <sub>(and your question was well-posted question too.  *Welcome*, by the way!)</sub>

## Further info on:

- [Quotation Marks in Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/quotation-marks-in-strings)
- [Declaring Variables in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-variables)
- [Breaking and Combining Statements in VB/VBA Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/how-to-break-and-combine-statements-in-code)
- [String Basics in VB/VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/string-basics)

Comment: Thank you, ashleedawg!  Your solution was just what I was looking for!  I thought I was in the neighborhood, and tried multiple variations, but just didn't get it. Thanks again.

Comment: ashleedawg, when I add a third criteria to my MATCH statement I get an "Error 2015" returned. Your help would be appreciated.  Here is my new statement: varFirstName2a = Evaluate("INDEX('[Master Staffing Matrix.xlsm]Master Staffing Matrix'!$C$2:$C$1500,MATCH(""" & strLastName & """&""" & strLabCat & """&""" & strStatus & """,'[Master Staffing Matrix.xlsm]Master Staffing Matrix'!$B$2:$B$1500&'[Master Staffing Matrix.xlsm]Master Staffing Matrix'!$H$2:$H$1500&'[Master Staffing Matrix.xlsm]Master Staffing Matrix'!$A$2:$A$1500,0))"). I thought i added the 3rd criteria correctly.

Comment: What is the full description of the error besides the error number, and which line is giving the error?

Comment: ashleedawg, the confounding thing is the code doesn't totally fail like it would with a "type mismatch" error. The line of code indicated above executes without fail, but the result in the receiving variable, varFirstName2a, has the value "Error2015" instead of the first name I am expecting. I can't find in any online documentation that there is a limitation of 2 concatenated values in the MATCH statement.  And, I thought I very carefully added the 3rd MATCH value with the appropriate pairing of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's easier to use a token replacement approach than trying to do a bunch of concatenation.

E.g.:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet, f, strFirstName

Set sht = Workbooks("MyMatrix.xlsm").Worksheets("MySheet")

f = "INDEX($C$2:$C$1000,MATCH(""{LastName}""&""{LabCat}"",$B$2:$B$1000&$H$2:$H$1000,0))"
f = Replace(f, "{LastName}", "Cain")
f = Replace(f, "{LabCat}", "AB01")

strFirstName = sht.Evaluate(f) '<< note using the Worksheet.Evaluate form here
```

Comment: Interesting idea. (Reminds me of [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in PHP.) I haven't seen that used in VB before, but I can think of some situations where that could be handy.

Comment: Agree. I use this approach heavily on HTML tables where you need to add specific text on specific parts of the table via VBA.

Comment: Thanks, Tim for your solution.  I haven't tried it yet, but I'm anxious to execute your suggestion and see how it works.  I'll report back.

Comment: Tim, I dropped your snippet of code into my module to step thru it and when i execute it, I get "Error 2042" returned to strFirstName. I believe, in other testing I've done, that essentially equates to "value not found", but I know the "Cain" and "ABO1" combination is valid - and is found with the long concatenated technique.  Am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Tim, one additional piece of info - the resulting value in "f" is: "INDEX($C$2:$C$1000,MATCH("Cain"&"AB01",$B$2:$B$1000&$H$2:$H$1000,0))"